# Multiple Threads in XPages Notescontext Error

Tags: java, xpages, xpinc

Hi I'm trying to create multiple Threads on an XPage
with the following code

```
public class ThreadTest implements Serializable {

private transient Vector<Integer> exvec;

private transient Map<String, Thread> searchThreads = new HashMap<String, Thread>();
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2503920777570603336L;
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

private class SearchThread extends Thread {

private ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus> executor;
private final ThreadTest owner;

private boolean ready = false;

public boolean isReady() {
    return this.ready;
}

public SearchThread(final ThreadTest owner, final String dbKey) {
    this.setName("SearchThread-dbKey-" + dbKey);
    this.owner = owner;

    this.executor = new ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus>(true) {
    protected IStatus run(Session session) throws NotesException {

        Database db =session.getDatabase("TestServer", "TestDB",false);
        if(db.isOpen())
        {
            exvec.add(db.getAllDocuments().getCount());
        }



        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
    };
}

public void run()  {
    try {
    this.executor.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    // release the monitor...
    synchronized (this.owner) {
        if (!isReady()) {
        ready = true;

        this.owner.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    }
}
}

public ThreadTest() {

    searchThreads = new HashMap<String, Thread>();
    exvec = new Vector<Integer>();
}



public void isThreaddingAvailable()
{


        searchThreads.put("Test", new SearchThread(this, "Test"));



        // step 2 - spawn each searchthread to run asynchronously...
        for (Map.Entry<String, Thread> searchThreadEntry : searchThreads.entrySet()) {
            SearchThread searchThread = (SearchThread) searchThreadEntry.getValue();

        searchThread.start();
        }

        // step 3 - wait until all searchthreads have completed...

        for (Map.Entry<String, Thread> searchThreadEntry : searchThreads.entrySet()) {
        SearchThread searchThread = (SearchThread) searchThreadEntry.getValue();
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!searchThread.isReady()) {
            try {

                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            }
        }
        }
        System.out.println(exvec);

}
}
```

But I got a problem every time I run a Thread in XPinc and try to access a other database 
I got this error:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: NotesContext cannot be null for ECL permission check
   (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.platform.NotesPlatform.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.XPagesSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.XPagesSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.XPagesSecurityManager.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.getParent(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.getAgentThreadGroup(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.bumpStaticActiveNotesThreadCount(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.initThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor.run(Unknown Source)
    at de.itwu.bean.ThreadTest$SearchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using sessionAsSigner or sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess to get a session with higher access?

Comment: If the user doesn't have access, do you still want to search? If not, just trap the error.

Comment: I have done some more tests and I was a little bit wrong in which cases the error is thrown. Every time I run a thread I and access a other Database I got this error.

Comment: Why do you do this in the first place? If you want to make multiple searched at once, I suggest writing an XPage which does the search and puts out the results as JSON or HTML or so, then in the originating XPage use dojo.xhrGet to call this "worker" XPage n-times and write it's result to the originating page.